# Why does xcode find interface for some methods but not others?

Tags: objective-c, macos, methods

I have a header file for an object as follows.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CSSRuleSet : NSObject{
    NSMutableArray *Selectors;
    NSArray *Properties;
    NSMutableArray *Values;
}

-(void)printElement;
-(void)initialiseArrays;
-(NSString *)getValue:(NSString *)Property;
-(void)assignValue:(NSString *)Property:(NSString *)Value;
-(void)addSelector:(NSString *)Selector;

@end
```

However, when I try to call methods on that object, some work, others throw up an error "no visible @interface for 'CSSStore' declares the selector 'initialiseArrays'".

The ones I am having problems with are printElement and initialiseArrays. For some reason I couldn't write a custom init function for this object either: it was there and didn't throw up any errors, it just wouldn't run.

Let me know if more information is needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean `CSSStore` when you've given us the definition for `CSSRuleSet`?

Comment: Are you overriding printElement from CSSStore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This class is CSSRuleSet. You appear to be trying to send messages intended for this class to a different class called CSSStore. The most likely reasons would be that either you've lost track of what object you're passing around at some point or you're not managing retains and releases correctly in a non-ARC program.